# Qt can't load any image in Release config

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

I was trying to build a project using QDir and QImage. I noticed that in Debug configuration everything works fine - QDir loads all the files in an app dir and writes whole paths to output. I can load an image to a QImage object, convert it and save.

Changing config to Release output's a totally different behaviour. I see QDir still able to read and write to the console screen good paths, but the loaded image is always NULL so it's not loaded at all. I've tried also to make it via .load(filename), .load(filepath) but it's not working. Format of my images is JPG.

Why is it happening?

Comment: are you using absolute paths or relative paths?

Comment: tried with just filename while image is in exe dir. Changing to absolute path does nothing.

Comment: Which platform are you on? Where did you get your Qt from? (SDK, Qt installer, self-compiled, etc.) Might be a plugin issue, if you're on Windows.

Comment: I'm on Windows 7, compiling with "Qt 4.8.1 for Desktop..." and i'm not using any plugins. Qt installed with Qt Creator from nokia servers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using relative paths while loading an image file. There is a chance that `release` and `debug` build paths might be different, either you intentionally or accidentally changed it.This happens if you are using qtcreator ide to build. I don't see any other reason.Try using absolute path or make the build directory the same for both.